# Fix Date and Time formats inside of Tibble

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a few CSV files that, when imported, have two columns, Date and Time. However, they are both muddled like so:

```
    Date                Time
03/03/14 00:00:00   12/30/99 09:01:12
```

i.e. they both have dates and times, when they should only have one or the other. How can I get rid of the extra noise there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to coerce your columns to something worthy of date and time, such as `as.POSIXct`. You can use `format` to extract whichever part of the date you wish.

```
x <- c("03/03/14 00:00:00", "12/30/99 09:01:12")
xy <- as.POSIXct(x, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")

> format(xy, "%m/%d/%y")
[1] "03/03/14" "12/30/99"
> format(xy, "%H:%M:%S")
[1] "00:00:00" "09:01:12"
```